# ProviderImpl not found Jboss 5.1

Tags: jax-ws, classloader, jboss5.x

I use jaxws 2.2.3 and Jboss 5.1 with JDK 6.

When calling ws client, I get

```
 java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found (see full stack trace below)
```

When I remove libs jbossws-native-*.jar from jboss/lib/endorsed everthing works fine. But they must be there.

I tried to tell jboss to use com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl:

1. META-INF/services/javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
2. -Djavax.xml.ws.spi.Provider
3. to read first my libs WEB-INF/jboss-classloading.xml

   ```
   <classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
         parent-first="false"
         domain="DefaultDomain"
         top-level-classloader="true"
         parent-domain="Ignored"
         export-all="NON_EMPTY"
         import-all="true">
   </classloading>
   ```

No luck. I spent whole day with this and I have no idea.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created endorsed libs for jboss instance - /jboss/server//lib/endorsed and copied these jars:

```
jaxws-api-2.2.3.jar
jaxws-rt-2.2.3.jar
jaxws-spring-1.8.jar
policy-2.2.2.jar
```

in my startup file I added:

```
set PRIVATE_ENDORSED_DIRS=%JBOSS_HOME%\server\portal_V1\lib\endorsed
```

then in run.bat:

```
if "x%PRIVATE_ENDORSED_DIRS%" == "x" (
  set "JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed"
) else (
  set "JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=%PRIVATE_ENDORSED_DIRS%;%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed"
)

REM set JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed
```

I couldn't play with JBoss libraries, because there are JBoss instances which don't belong to me and I know nothing about them.

Comment: When I did the above I get the following:  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage

Comment: I had to copy over the following JARs in order to get everything to work correctly:  streambuffer.jar, stax-ex.jar, policy.jar, jaxws-rt.jar, jaxws-api.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxb-api.jar and gmbal-api-only.jar.