# JaxWS ClassCastException on JBoss

Tags: java, jax-ws, jboss5.x

I'm using JBoss 5.1.0.GA (for JDK6), and jaxws 2.2.6.
When I invoke the webservice, I get the following exception:

> java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider:
>   Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be
>   instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException   at
>   org.jboss.resource.work.WorkWrapper.completed(WorkWrapper.java:283)
>     at
>     org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicTaskWrapper.taskCompleted(BasicTaskWrapper.java:367)
>     at
>     org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicTaskWrapper.run(BasicTaskWrapper.java:268)
>     at
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
>
> Caused by:
>     java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider:
>     Provider org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl could not be
>   instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException   at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:207)   at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:164)   at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:353)   at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:421)   at
>   javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:180)
>   at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:140)   at
>   javax.xml.ws.Service.(Service.java:92)
>   [...]
>   ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException   at
>   java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:2990)   at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:345)
>   ... 14 more

I also tried to update jbossws to version 3.4.0 from 3.1.2.GA, nothing changed.
I've read a lot of suggestions related to checking jars in lib/endorsed of JBoss, so this is the content:

```
activation.jar
jaxb-api.jar
jaxws-api.jar
jbossws-native-factories.jar
resolver.jar
serializer.jar stax-api.jar
xalan.jar
xercesImpl.jar
```

I've also added the switch -verbose:class to the JVM:

```
[Loaded org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl from jar:file:/Users/carlo/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/lib/jbossws-native-core.jar!/]
```

and that class extends `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` (http://bit.ly/LK9bNE)

Can someone help me what's going on here?

**EDIT 1**
Ok, so I see that the ClassCastException is raised from: ServiceLoader.java line 345

```
S p = service.cast(Class.forName(cn, true, loader).newInstance());
```

when service.cast is called, `this` is `javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider` and the arg to cast  is `org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl`.
I still fail to understand the problem though.

Comment: You could debug it using Eclipse and put a breakpoint on the exception: ClassCastException

Comment: PS I've had a few problems with JAX-WS because it (the reference impl anyhow) is now integrated into the JDK. If you have another version of it on your classpath aswell as the version in the JDK, things like this tend to happen. Never heard of jbossws but it sounds like it could be a JAX-WS implementation

Comment: I have those kind of problems before, in fact in my maven dependency I've excluded: javax.xml.stream, stax, saaj-impl, saaj-api and mimepull. And made the errors I hade disappear.

Comment: If you've fixed it, I would answer your own question so people searching will see the solution. And - well done ;].

Comment: I was talking about another problem, unfortunately, not the one related to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to solve my problem: I put `jaxws-rt.jar` in `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed`.

**EDIT**
I had the same problem on JBoss 5.1 EAP, and to solve it, the steps are a little different:
in `$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed` I removed the old jaxb-api.jar, then copied

- jaxb-api.jar
- jaxb-impl.jar
- jaxws-api.jar
- jaxws-rt.jar

from the latest jaxws-ri package, and eventually it worked.

Comment: When I added in the 4 jar files identified above, I was then required to add in several others.  Does the above work as is or am I missing something here.

Comment: Can you provide any more info.  I am running JBoss 5.1 AS.  I have a web service client created using JDK 1.6_22 with JAXWS RI 2.2.7.  I am unable to use the client when it is deployed on JBoss.  Client works fine in stand alone mode.

Comment: JBoss 5.1 or the EAP version? In the first case I've downloaded this one: jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6.zip and I don't remember adding anymore jars. It was 3 months ago though ;)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.  I am running JBoss 5.1 EAP along with JDK 1.6_22.

I did things slightly different.  I combined the solution by Carlo plus [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842286/providerimpl-not-found-jboss-5-1).

I created an endorsed folder under $JBOSS_HOME/server//lib/endorsed.  I then copied over streambuffer.jar, stax-ex.jar, policy.jar, jaxws-rt.jar, jaxws-api.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxb-api.jar and gmbal-api-only.jar.

I left the $JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed alone.

Doing this, I was able to get it to work it all to work

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on JBoss 5.1 EAP
Instead of putting jar files into JBOSS application server it is more robust when you alter class loading logic by isolating WAR with Overriding Server Classes (http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/classloadingconfiguration) In my case I have 3 environments. With this solution I can move war file from one JBOSS instance to another and it will still work.

I resolved this problem by:
Adding this to jboss-web.xml:

```
<class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
    <loader-repository>
        com.example:archive=unique-archive-name
        <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
```

...

and by adding requierd jars into war (jaxb-api.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxws-api.jar, jaxws-rt.jar)