# How to know Jboss EAP version

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

I am using JBoss5.1.0.GA.

How to know whether is this a EAP version or normal? Actually I am stuck in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048655/jaxws-classcastexception-on-jboss). So trying to solve it by seeing comments.

Comment: Start the server with `-version` then you should see it.

Comment: server is already started and I cannot stop. Is there any way ?

Comment: There is no problem to run this command, even the sever is started. It will print only the sever version not start the server.

Comment: ok..like for java version we type java -version. for jboss version..what should I type ?

Comment: Depends how you start your server. One standard way `standalone.sh -version` (like in Java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the required permissions to execute the command

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect
# next two lines to enter in the JBoss command line interface
/:read-attribute(name=product-name)
/:read-attribute(name=product-version)
```

Or you can use JConsole and explore the `jboss.as:server` MBean the attributes have the names

```
productName
productVersion
```

Or (might not work with 5.1.0 GA, was tested with a newer version)

```
cat $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/as/product/eap/dir/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Answer (score 0):

The **JBoss EAP 5.1** is provided as a bundle, which contains not only the application server but also other components:

```
jboss-eap-5.1/
    jboss-as/
    mod_cluster/
    picketlink/
    resteasy/
    seam/
```

All **JAR files are signed in the EAP**. You can find the information about signatures in META-INF folder:

```
$ unzip -l jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/lib/concurrent.jar
Archive:  jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/lib/concurrent.jar
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
    25286  2010-05-04 17:19   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    25376  2010-09-14 21:10   META-INF/JBOSSCOD.SF
     2826  2010-09-14 21:10   META-INF/JBOSSCOD.RSA
....
```

The EAP contains **production** server profile:

```
$ ls jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/server/
all  default  minimal  production  standard  web
```