# Exceptions calling Webservice client from JBoss

Tags: jboss, jax-ws, java-6, atg

I am running into an issue with a web service created using the latest jaxws-ri.  I have created a client for SVS Web Service API.

I am deploying this web service client under ATG 10.0.3/JBoss 5.1 EA/ JDK 1.6_22 / RedHat 5.4.  I have created a [self cert](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SSLSetup).

When I run the client in a stand alone mode (not deployed to JBoss) it works just fine.

Now running under the server I am getting the following stacktrace and I not really sure at this point as to what the problem is.  I have contacted the vendor to see if they are even seeing me knocking on the door to determine if it just dieing on my end

```
10:37:36,780 WARN  [WSDL11Reader] UsingAddressing extensibility element not supported yet.
```

and

```
    10:37:40,074 ERROR [CommonClient] Exception caught while (preparing for) performing the invocation: 
java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:253)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.invoke(SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.java:71)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:360)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:231)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:157)
        at $Proxy153.balanceInquiry(Unknown Source)
        at com.scvl.giftcard.SVSGiftCardService.balanceInquiry(SVSGiftCardService.java:87)
        at com.scvl.giftcard.GiftCardBalanceInquiryFormHandler.handleBalanceInquiry(GiftCardBalanceInquiryFormHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at atg.droplet.EventSender.sendEvent(EventSender.java:582)
        at atg.droplet.FormTag.doSendEvents(FormTag.java:800)
        at atg.droplet.FormTag.sendEvents(FormTag.java:649)
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.sendEvents(DropletEventServlet.java:523)
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.service(DropletEventServlet.java:550)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.commerce.order.CommerceCommandServlet.service(CommerceCommandServlet.java:128)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.commerce.promotion.PromotionServlet.service(PromotionServlet.java:191)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.AccessControlServlet.service(AccessControlServlet.java:655)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.sessionsaver.SessionSaverServlet.service(SessionSaverServlet.java:2425)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:169)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.multisite.SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:139)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.SessionEventTrigger.service(SessionEventTrigger.java:477)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfilePropertyServlet.service(ProfilePropertyServlet.java:208)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.search.servlet.SearchClickThroughServlet.service(SearchClickThroughServlet.java:415)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfileRequestServlet.service(ProfileRequestServlet.java:437)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.projects.store.servlet.pipeline.ProtocolSwitchServlet.service(ProtocolSwitchServlet.java:290)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.ondemand.servlet.pipeline.NetscalerServlet.service(NetscalerServlet.java:86)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:469)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.URLArgumentPipelineServlet.service(URLArgumentPipelineServlet.java:280)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:370)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.sso.PassportServlet.service(PassportServlet.java:554)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.security.ThreadUserBinderServlet.service(ThreadUserBinderServlet.java:91)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.dtm.TransactionPipelineServlet.service(TransactionPipelineServlet.java:212)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.multisite.SiteContextPipelineServlet.service(SiteContextPipelineServlet.java:383)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1174)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:857)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:250)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not connect http client invoker after 1 attempt(s)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.makeInvocation(HTTPClientInvoker.java:250)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.transport(HTTPClientInvoker.java:162)
        at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:167)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:2034)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:877)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:232)
        ... 80 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Envelope1_1Impl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPElementImpl**
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.<init>(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:57)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:136)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:96)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:294)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageUnMarshallerHTTP.read(SOAPMessageUnMarshallerHTTP.java:82)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.readResponse(HTTPClientInvoker.java:584)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:381)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.makeInvocation(HTTPClientInvoker.java:232)
        ... 85 more
10:37:40,079 ERROR [SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
java.io.IOException: Could not transmit message
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:253)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.invoke(SOAPProtocolConnectionHTTP.java:71)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:360)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:231)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:157)
        at $Proxy153.balanceInquiry(Unknown Source)
        at com.scvl.giftcard.SVSGiftCardService.balanceInquiry(SVSGiftCardService.java:87)
        at com.scvl.giftcard.GiftCardBalanceInquiryFormHandler.handleBalanceInquiry(GiftCardBalanceInquiryFormHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at atg.droplet.EventSender.sendEvent(EventSender.java:582)
        at atg.droplet.FormTag.doSendEvents(FormTag.java:800)
        at atg.droplet.FormTag.sendEvents(FormTag.java:649)
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.sendEvents(DropletEventServlet.java:523)
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.service(DropletEventServlet.java:550)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.commerce.order.CommerceCommandServlet.service(CommerceCommandServlet.java:128)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.commerce.promotion.PromotionServlet.service(PromotionServlet.java:191)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.AccessControlServlet.service(AccessControlServlet.java:655)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.sessionsaver.SessionSaverServlet.service(SessionSaverServlet.java:2425)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:169)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.multisite.SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:139)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.SessionEventTrigger.service(SessionEventTrigger.java:477)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfilePropertyServlet.service(ProfilePropertyServlet.java:208)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.search.servlet.SearchClickThroughServlet.service(SearchClickThroughServlet.java:415)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfileRequestServlet.service(ProfileRequestServlet.java:437)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.projects.store.servlet.pipeline.ProtocolSwitchServlet.service(ProtocolSwitchServlet.java:290)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.ondemand.servlet.pipeline.NetscalerServlet.service(NetscalerServlet.java:86)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:469)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.URLArgumentPipelineServlet.service(URLArgumentPipelineServlet.java:280)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:370)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.sso.PassportServlet.service(PassportServlet.java:554)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.security.ThreadUserBinderServlet.service(ThreadUserBinderServlet.java:91)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.dtm.TransactionPipelineServlet.service(TransactionPipelineServlet.java:212)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.multisite.SiteContextPipelineServlet.service(SiteContextPipelineServlet.java:383)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1174)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:857)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:250)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not connect http client invoker after 1 attempt(s)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.makeInvocation(HTTPClientInvoker.java:250)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.transport(HTTPClientInvoker.java:162)
        at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:167)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:2034)
        at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:877)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.client.HTTPRemotingConnection.invoke(HTTPRemotingConnection.java:232)
        ... 80 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Envelope1_1Impl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPElementImpl**
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.<init>(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:57)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:136)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.EnvelopeBuilderDOM.build(EnvelopeBuilderDOM.java:96)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:294)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageUnMarshallerHTTP.read(SOAPMessageUnMarshallerHTTP.java:82)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.readResponse(HTTPClientInvoker.java:584)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:381)
        at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.makeInvocation(HTTPClientInvoker.java:232)
        ... 85 more
10:37:40,093 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
**javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl**
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.handleRemoteException(ClientImpl.java:310)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:243)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:171)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:157)
        at $Proxy153.balanceInquiry(Unknown Source)
        at com.scvl.giftcard.SVSGiftCardService.balanceInquiry(SVSGiftCardService.java:87)
        at com.scvl.giftcard.GiftCardBalanceInquiryFormHandler.handleBalanceInquiry(GiftCardBalanceInquiryFormHandler.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at atg.droplet.EventSender.sendEvent(EventSender.java:582)
        at atg.droplet.FormTag.doSendEvents(FormTag.java:800)
        at atg.droplet.FormTag.sendEvents(FormTag.java:649)
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.sendEvents(DropletEventServlet.java:523)
        at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.service(DropletEventServlet.java:550)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.commerce.order.CommerceCommandServlet.service(CommerceCommandServlet.java:128)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.commerce.promotion.PromotionServlet.service(PromotionServlet.java:191)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.AccessControlServlet.service(AccessControlServlet.java:655)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.sessionsaver.SessionSaverServlet.service(SessionSaverServlet.java:2425)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(PageEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:169)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.multisite.SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.service(SiteSessionEventTriggerPipelineServlet.java:139)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.SessionEventTrigger.service(SessionEventTrigger.java:477)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfilePropertyServlet.service(ProfilePropertyServlet.java:208)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.search.servlet.SearchClickThroughServlet.service(SearchClickThroughServlet.java:415)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.ProfileRequestServlet.service(ProfileRequestServlet.java:437)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.projects.store.servlet.pipeline.ProtocolSwitchServlet.service(ProtocolSwitchServlet.java:290)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.ondemand.servlet.pipeline.NetscalerServlet.service(NetscalerServlet.java:86)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:469)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.URLArgumentPipelineServlet.service(URLArgumentPipelineServlet.java:280)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(PathAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:370)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.userprofiling.sso.PassportServlet.service(PassportServlet.java:554)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.security.ThreadUserBinderServlet.service(ThreadUserBinderServlet.java:91)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.dtm.TransactionPipelineServlet.service(TransactionPipelineServlet.java:212)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.multisite.SiteContextPipelineServlet.service(SiteContextPipelineServlet.java:383)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:135)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1174)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:857)
        at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:250)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl cannot be cast to org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl**
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.createSOAPMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:298)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.toSOAPMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:257)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.exceptionToFaultMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS.java:188)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.handler.HandlerChainExecutor.handleFault(HandlerChainExecutor.java:194)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.callFaultHandlerChain(ClientImpl.java:161)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonClient.invoke(CommonClient.java:432)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.client.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:231)
        ... 77 more
```

Comment: I added the following to my jboss start up script:  -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.  No change

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fixed the issue but using info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048655/jaxws-classcastexception-on-jboss) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842286/providerimpl-not-found-jboss-5-1)

With some slight modifications.

I created an endorsed folder under $JBOSS_HOME/server//lib/endorsed.  I then copied over streambuffer.jar, stax-ex.jar, policy.jar, jaxws-rt.jar, jaxws-api.jar, jaxb-impl.jar, jaxb-api.jar and gmbal-api-only.jar.

I left the $JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed alone.

Doing this, I was able to get it to work it all to work